# Symfony test : The request was not redirected

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm working on Symfony tests and I have a problem that I can't solve since hours...
I've got a simple twig template with a form :

```
<form action="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }}" method="post" class="add-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="coinSelect"  name="coin" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select the coin</option>
                        <option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
                        <option value="ethereum">Ethereum</option>
                        <option value="ripple">Ripple</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number"   name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" name="value" placeholder="Value price" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" >ADD</button>

            </form>
```

And here's the test function :

```
/** @test */
public function addCoin(): void
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request("GET", "/add");
    $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    $form = $crawler->selectButton("AJOUTER")->form();
    $form['value'] = 40000;
    $form['quantity'] = 1;
    $form['coin']->select('bitcoin');
    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
    $this->assertSelectorExists('#confirmation');
}
```

When I launch the phpunit test, I've got this one error:
**LogicException: The request was not redirected.**

Maybe it comes from the value and quantity field (I tried with quotes : '40000' and '1' but doesnt work either...)

Thanks for your help !!

EDIT :
Here's the Controller code :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\AddCoinType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Transactions;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class AddController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/add', name: 'app_add')]
    public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $confirmation = '';
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $transaction = new Transactions();

        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $transaction->setCoin($request->request->get("coin"));
            $transaction->setValue($request->request->get("value"));
            $transaction->setQuantity($request->request->get("quantity"));
            $transaction->setDate(new \DateTime());
            $entityManager->persist($transaction);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $confirmation = '<p id="confirmation" >Well done</p>';
         }

        return $this->render('add/index.html.twig', [
            'confirmation' => $confirmation,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: but does the controller redirect after form submission? if no, then there is no redirection. You should probably show your controller code too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The form is redirecting to the same page and then a paragraph shall appear with a confirmation id (p#confirmation). But when I remove the "followRedirect" line to test directly the #confirmation, it doesn't work either. The error is : Failed asserting that the Crawler matches selector "#confirmation". In conclusion, it seems that the form is never submitted.

Comment: UPDATE : Controller code added in the question.

Comment: I don't see any redirect in your controller, so testing for that will always fail... submitting a form is not a redirection. As a side note, you might want to go find some Symfony tutorials (or [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-forms)) on handling forms. For example, you do not need to create the request from globals, simply inject it. See the docs for more, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realize I better had to use the symfony form builder and I'll do it for further projects. But do you have an idea about my second error (when I remove the redirecting test and just test if the #confirmation is displayed) : Failed asserting that the Crawler matches selector "#confirmation".

Comment: does the controller work through a browser?

Comment: Through the browser all works perfectly. And if I add the id #confirmation to an existing object (a field for example), the test succeeds. The problem is probably that the paragraph with the id #confirmation is generated after submitting the form, but I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

craigh said : "For example, you do not need to create the request from globals, simply inject it". That's it !

```
public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request): Response
```

Now all works ! Thanks for your help craigh :)